# JSON List conversion

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe, python-requests

My list of (tuples of) JSON values looks as follows:

```
testJson = [('{"drivernumber":1, "speed" : ["30.5", "40", "50", "25.25"]}',),
            ('{"drivernumber":2, "speed" : ["25.25", "10.11", "11", "50"]}',),
            ('{"drivernumber":3, "speed" : ["40", "50", "80", "42"]}',)
           ]
```

I created the below data structure:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, ArrayType, StringType
readSchema = StructType([
                   StructField("drivernumber", IntegerType(), True), 
                   StructField("speed", StringType(FloatType(), True), True)])
```

Then created a DataFrame:

```
df = (spark.read.schema(readSchema).json(sc.parallelize(testJson)))
display(df)
```

Ultimately, I need to get the below output but at the moment, my DF (after above step) only has NULLS, and I don't know why. Any leads or tips would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

```
speed  drivercount
50          3
40          2
25.25       2
11          1
....        ....
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need a list of one-element tuples?

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon - Just that data is passed by the broker in this format.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define the schema for it, Simply Use

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(testJson))
```